# How to use assign labels at intervals to x-axis ticks in discrete fashion?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

The dataframe looks like this:

```
    > head(melted_sensors_ovens_df)
         macid               variable value
1 D828C9012DB2 ERDx5205.DISPLAY_TIMER     1
2 D828C9011393 ERDx5205.DISPLAY_TIMER     2
3 D828C9014C85 ERDx5205.DISPLAY_TIMER     3
4 D828C90121FE ERDx5205.DISPLAY_TIMER     4
5 D828C90139EE ERDx5205.DISPLAY_TIMER     5
6 D828C901551F ERDx5205.DISPLAY_TIMER     6
```

I have plotted a data with following command:

```
ggplot(melted_sensors_ovens_df[order(melted_sensors_ovens_df$value), ], 
       aes(variable, value, colour=variable)) + 
    geom_point() +
    labs(x="Sensors", y="Present / Absent in each Oven", title="") + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(0, 10, 0.25), labels=as.character(seq(0, 10, 0.25))) + 
    theme(legend.position = "none", 
          axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
          axis.title.x = element_text(size=40), 
          axis.title.y = element_text(size=40))
```

The output image looks like this:
[image]

Now the x-axis is actually a list of 149 sensors which I can't assign as it will get a bit messy. I would want to know how to assign labels S1, S30, S60, S90, etc. (i.e. labels at some interval). How to achieve this? I am thinking about using scale_x_discrete() or is there any other way?

Comment: Yes. See arguments `breaks` and `labels`. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_discrete.html